# Prestashop - Carrier list not refreshed when address changed

Tags: prestashop, prestashop-1.6

I have a prestashop website with a five step checkout, and I just realized that when I change the delivery address, in the next step the carrier list in not updated, I need to refresh manually the page in my browser to have the right ones.

Any idea where it may come from or what I could do to get around?

My version of prestashop is 1.6.0.14

Thank you

Comment: But when you move from delivery address to carrier list the page doesn't get refreshed? Are you using default template?

Comment: try converting the five step checkout to one step

Answer (score 0):

put this:

```
$this->context->smarty->force_compile = true;
```

in: OrderController.php:

```
public function initContent(){
```

after `case 1:` and `case 2:`